# free jqGrid max number of records in a group

Tags: jqgrid, max, record

jqGrid 4.15.5 is displaying only 10000 records in a group and breaks without error and not processing other groups. Is there a way to increase the number of rows in a group?
Thank You,
Regards,
TSB

Comment: I think this is a option and you should read the docs (if any) for this purpose, otherwise you will need to look into the source.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is late post but after Tony Tomov answer looked into the source and found out a property named maxRowNum which defaulted to 10000 and when I tweaked it I was able to display more than 10000 records.
Thank you Tony